# Issue getting values from my JSP page using a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to get details from my registration form , using a servlet and then displaying all the existing users. 
I know im going wrong in the servlet. Cant really find out where.

this is my reg.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="UserController.java">
            <center>
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Enter Information Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="pass" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">Already registered!! <a href="index.jsp">Login Here</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my servlet code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import com.shreya.dao.UserDao;
import com.shreya.model.Details;
import com.shreya.model.User;

public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT = "/user.jsp";
    private static String LIST_USER = "/listUser.jsp";
    private UserDao dao;

    public UserController() {
        super();
        dao = new UserDao();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String forward="";
String act = request.getParameter("act");
         if (act != null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && act.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
            forward= "/Login.jsp";
            }

         else if (act != null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && act.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
        {
            int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
            dao.deleteUser(userId);
            forward = LIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());    
        } else if (act!=null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && act.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
            forward = INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));
            User user1 = dao.getUserById(userId);
            request.setAttribute("user", user1);
        } else if (act!=null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") && act.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")){
            forward = LIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
        } else 
            forward = "/Login.jsp";

                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);

    }


        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        User user = new User();
        Details details = new Details();
        user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
        user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
        details.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
        details.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
      //  details.setId(request.getParameter("id"));
        String str=request.getParameter("username");
        String str1=request.getParameter("password");



if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("shreya")&&str1.equalsIgnoreCase("singh"))
         System.out.println("Login!");
     else
     {
      System.out.println("Login failed!");


      request.setAttribute("users",dao.getAllUsers());

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/listUser.jsp").forward(request, response); 

        }
     }
}
```

EDIT 1 :

```
else if (act!=null && !act.equalsIgnoreCase("null") &&    act.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
        forward = LIST_USER;
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
```

passed an action register to save the values in the doGet method.
How do i modify accordingly in the dopost?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
details.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
details.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
```

to this:

```
details.setUsername(request.getParameter("uname"));
details.setPassword(request.getParameter("pass"));
```

The names of the inputs must match the name of request parameter you're getting.

EDIT: some basic suggestions:

don't access request parameters directly for storing, prepare a simple utility function to take care of null value. Request parameters will be null when not issued, but will be "" if issued empty.

Enumerate public static String constants for your request parameters name, having magic string in code can lead to loosing grip on it:

```
public static String PARAM_USERNAME = "uname";
public static String PARAM_PASSWORD = "pass";
```

If a parameter is mandatory, just check it for having an actual value and handle the error/situation, having raw exception in a servlet can be a pain to debug later on.

Foresee a request dumping method (keep it in an Utility class) just to log out all the request parameters, attributes and HTTP headers, will save you plenty of this situations while debugging.

EDIT2: try invoking this doPost method and see what happens (change parameter's name to right ones):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        out.println("Dumping Request");
        Enumeration<?> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
            String paramValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
            out.println("   " + paramName + ": " + paramValue);
        }

        // User user = new User();
        // Details details = new Details();
        // user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
        // user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
        // details.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
        // details.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
        //  details.setId(request.getParameter("id"));
        // String str = request.getParameter("username");
        // String str1 = request.getParameter("password");

        // if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("shreya") && str1.equalsIgnoreCase("singh"))
        //     System.out.println("Login!");
        // else
        // {
        //     System.out.println("Login failed!");    
        //     request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());    
        //     request.getRequestDispatcher("/listUser.jsp").forward(request, response);    
        // }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        out.println("Exception in servlet");
        t.printStackTrace(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error , saying that the requested resource is not available

Comment: restart the application server, and check its log for the error. Probably your code is going in NullPointerException and thus the error page.

Comment: ive changed the parameter names ,but it still gives me an error , plus i need to pass an action through the servlet to access the details

Comment: debug. you have to find where your doPost raises an exception. Try just accessing the request parameters and dumping them on response.getWriter().

Comment: i tried passing an action through the servlet , its still not working